# How do i capture interleaved stdout and stderr in a goloang ssh session?

Tags: go, ssh

How can i capture interleaved stderr/stdout output from an ssh.Session in go to model shell redirection of the form `2>&1`?

I tried to it do by combining the output of the stdout and stderr pipes from the session into a multi-reader and then used a scanner to capture the data from the multi-reader asynchronously in a go routine.

That worked, sort of. All of the data was caught but the stderr data was not interleaved. It appeared at the end.

I was able to cause the stderr output to appear at the beginning by reversing the order of the arguments to io.MultiReader() but it was still not interleaved.

Here is the output I expected.

```
$ ./gentestdata -i 5 -d -l -n 12 -w 32 -a 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
     1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     9 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    11 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    12 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am

$ # note that two of the lines were output to stderr
$ ./gentestdata -i 5 -d -l -n 12 -w 32 -a 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet' 1>/dev/null
     5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
```

> The gentestdata program is something I developed to allow me to do this sort of test. The source can be found here: https://github.com/jlinoff/gentestdata.

Here is the output I saw:

```
$ ./sshx $(pwd)/gentestdata -i 5 -d -l -n 12 -w 32 -a 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
     1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     6 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     7 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     8 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     9 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    11 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    12 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
     5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
    10 Lorem ipsum dolor sit am
```

Note that the last two lines from stderr are out of order.

Here is the complete source code. Note the exec() function.

```
// Simple demonstration of how I thought that I could capture interleaved
// stdout and stderr output generated during go ssh.Session to model the
// bash 2>&1 redirection behavior.
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func main() {
    user := strings.TrimSpace(os.Getenv("LOGNAME"))
    auth := getPassword(fmt.Sprintf("%v's password: ", user))
    addr := "localhost:22"
    if len(os.Args) > 1 {
        cmd := getCmd(os.Args[1:])
        config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
            User: user,
            Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
                ssh.Password(auth),
            },
        }
        exec(cmd, addr, config)
    }
}

// Execute the command.
func exec(cmd string, addr string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) {
    // Create the connection.
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, config)
    check(err)
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    check(err)
    defer session.Close()

    // Collect the output from stdout and stderr.
    // The idea is to duplicate the shell IO redirection
    // 2>&1 where both streams are interleaved.
    stdoutPipe, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    check(err)
    stderrPipe, err := session.StderrPipe()
    check(err)
    outputReader := io.MultiReader(stdoutPipe, stderrPipe)
    outputScanner := bufio.NewScanner(outputReader)

    // Start the session.
    err = session.Start(cmd)
    check(err)

    // Capture the output asynchronously.
    outputLine := make(chan string)
    outputDone := make(chan bool)
    go func(scan *bufio.Scanner, line chan string, done chan bool) {
        defer close(line)
        defer close(done)
        for scan.Scan() {
            line <- scan.Text()
        }
        done <- true
    }(outputScanner, outputLine, outputDone)

    // Use a custom wait.
    outputBuf := ""
    running := true
    for running {
        select {
        case <-outputDone:
            running = false
        case line := <-outputLine:
            outputBuf += line + "\n"
        }
    }
    session.Close()

    // Output the data.
    fmt.Print(outputBuf)
}

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        _, _, lineno, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
        log.Fatalf("ERROR:%v %v", lineno, e)
    }
}

// Convert a slice of tokens to a command string.
// It inserts quotes where necessary.
func getCmd(args []string) (cmd string) {
    cmd = ""
    for i, token := range args {
        if i > 0 {
            cmd += " "
        }
        cmd += quote(token)
    }
    return
}

// Quote an individual token.
// Very simple, not suitable for production.
func quote(token string) string {
    q := false
    r := ""
    for _, c := range token {
        switch c {
        case '"':
            q = true
            r += "\""
        case ' ', '\t':
            q = true
        }
        r += string(c)
    }
    if q {
        r = "\"" + r + "\""
    }
    return r
}

func getPassword(prompt string) string {
    // Get the initial state of the terminal.
    initialTermState, e1 := terminal.GetState(syscall.Stdin)
    if e1 != nil {
        panic(e1)
    }

    // Restore it in the event of an interrupt.
    // CITATION: Konstantin Shaposhnikov - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/kTVAbtee9UA
    c := make(chan os.Signal)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, os.Kill)
    go func() {
        <-c
        _ = terminal.Restore(syscall.Stdin, initialTermState)
        os.Exit(1)
    }()

    // Now get the password.
    fmt.Print(prompt)
    p, err := terminal.ReadPassword(syscall.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Stop looking for ^C on the channel.
    signal.Stop(c)

    // Return the password as a string.
    return string(p)
}
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

### Update #1: Tried suggestion from JimB

Modified the exec function as follows:

```
// Execute the command.
func exec(cmd string, addr string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) {
    // Create the connection.
    conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", addr, config)
    check(err)
    session, err := conn.NewSession()
    check(err)
    defer session.Close()

    // Run the command.
    b, err := session.CombinedOutput(cmd)
    check(err)

    // Output the data.
    outputBuf := string(b)
    fmt.Print(outputBuf)
}
```

It changed things but the output was still not interleaved. This is the output
from the test run.

```
     5 9FqBZonjaaWDcXMm8biABker
    10 zMd1JTT3ZGR5mEuJOaJCo9AZ
     1 bPlNFGdSC2wd8f2QnFhk5A84
     2 H9H2FHFuvUs9Jz8UvBHv3Vc5
     3 wsp2nChCIwVQztA2n95rXrtz
     4 eDZ0tHBxFq6Pysq3N267L1vq
     6 DF2EsjYyTQWCfIuilZxV2FCn
     7 fGOILa0u1wXnEw1GDGuvdSew
     8 fj84Qyu6uRn8CTECWzT5s4ZJ
     9 KykqOn91fMwNqsk2Wrc5uhk2
    11 0p7opMMsnA87D6TSTAXY5NAC
    12 HYixe6pj0dHuKlxQyyNenUNQ
```

Now the stderr data shows up at the beginning.

### Update #2: Showed the SSH also separated the FDs

After JimB's last comment I decided to run experiment using SSH on both a Mac and on a Linux host using gentest. Note that SSH also separates the output so this issue is resolved.

#### Terminal

```
$ # Interleaved on the terminal.
$ /user/jlinoff/bin/gentestdata -l -i 5 -w 32 -n 12
     1 bPlNFGdSC2wd8f2QnFhk5A84
     2 H9H2FHFuvUs9Jz8UvBHv3Vc5
     3 wsp2nChCIwVQztA2n95rXrtz
     4 eDZ0tHBxFq6Pysq3N267L1vq
     5 9FqBZonjaaWDcXMm8biABker
     6 DF2EsjYyTQWCfIuilZxV2FCn
     7 fGOILa0u1wXnEw1GDGuvdSew
     8 fj84Qyu6uRn8CTECWzT5s4ZJ
     9 KykqOn91fMwNqsk2Wrc5uhk2
    10 zMd1JTT3ZGR5mEuJOaJCo9AZ
    11 0p7opMMsnA87D6TSTAXY5NAC
    12 HYixe6pj0dHuKlxQyyNenUNQ
```

#### SSH

```
$ ssh hqxsv-cmdev3-jlinoff /user/jlinoff/bin/gentestdata -l -i 5 -w 32 -n 12
     1 bPlNFGdSC2wd8f2QnFhk5A84
     2 H9H2FHFuvUs9Jz8UvBHv3Vc5
     3 wsp2nChCIwVQztA2n95rXrtz
     4 eDZ0tHBxFq6Pysq3N267L1vq
     6 DF2EsjYyTQWCfIuilZxV2FCn
     7 fGOILa0u1wXnEw1GDGuvdSew
     8 fj84Qyu6uRn8CTECWzT5s4ZJ
     9 KykqOn91fMwNqsk2Wrc5uhk2
    11 0p7opMMsnA87D6TSTAXY5NAC
    12 HYixe6pj0dHuKlxQyyNenUNQ
     5 9FqBZonjaaWDcXMm8biABker
    10 zMd1JTT3ZGR5mEuJOaJCo9AZ
```

Note that the last two lines (stderr) are not interleaved.

Comment: try to flush the stderr and stdout after writing. It might be cached somewhere.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a good idea but how do I flush stderr and stdout from the ssh session? I don't have a writer, only the pipes that are handled by the multi-reader in the scanner. Can you provide a code fragment?

Comment: @JoeLinoff: from the [`io.MultiReader` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#MultiReader): "They're read sequentially". Does [`Session.CombinedOutput`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.CombinedOutput) not do what you want?

Comment: Thank you @JimB, I missed that completely. It certainly explains what I am seeing so the behavior is correct. Session.CombinedOutput might do the trick. I will try that.

Comment: @JimB, I tried your suggestion (see update #1 above). Unfortunately Session.CombinedOutput also did not interleave the stdout/stderr data. Do you have any other ideas that i could try?

Comment: The only way to really get the exact same behavior as `2>&1`, is to have a shell execute your command with that redirection, or have your command write to one FD on its own. Even without ssh in the mix, there's never going to be synchronization between stdout and stderr. The output is going to 2 separate FDs (where stderr may have different buffering or latency), and sent over 2 separate channels.

Comment: Thanks @JimB. I appreciate the insight.

I have been perusing the SSH source code and came to the same conclusion. I was just hoping that I was missing something that would make it possible. 

I even tried an experiment where I created two separate channels (stderr and stdout), with separate go routines to populate them. They still did not interleave because, as you said, they were separate FDs. The only workaround I could think of was to insert a time field that could be used for ordering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @JimB's feedback and my experiment in update #2, you must specify `&>` or `2>&1` in the shell command to interleave stderr and stdout.